# ajax code not responding on ie8 and ie9

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, internet-explorer

```
 function search_val()  {

    $("#company_code_nr1").click();

    $("#poc").click();
    $("#company_code_nr").click();
    $("#subcompany_code_nr").click();
    $("#cs_code_nr").click();
    $("#invoice_id_nr").click();
    $("#user_code_tx").click();
    $("#owner_code_nr").click();
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }
else
  {
// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

   var str=$("#company_code_nr").val();
   var str2=$("#subcompany_code_nr").val();
   var str3=$("#product_code_nr").val();
   var str4=$("#invoice_code_nr").val();

  var url="hotkeydetail.php?f3="+str+"&c4="+str2+"&c6="+str3+"&c7="+str4;

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();


             }
```

hi i am using code for getting content on another page every things is OK Mozilla and   other browser also work on IE 10 . but not responding on ie8 and ie9. please help me. thanks

Comment: Why on Gods green earth would you decide to use jQuery, and then not use it for ajax, one of the things it does best ?

Comment: Open up the browser console and see what is being printed

Comment: nothing is work on ie8 .

Comment: please if u all guys have any solution help me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery Ajax like this:

```
function search_val()  {

    $("#company_code_nr1").click();

    $("#poc").click();
    $("#company_code_nr").click();
    $("#subcompany_code_nr").click();
    $("#cs_code_nr").click();
    $("#invoice_id_nr").click();
    $("#user_code_tx").click();
    $("#owner_code_nr").click();

    var str=$("#company_code_nr").val();
    var str2=$("#subcompany_code_nr").val();
    var str3=$("#product_code_nr").val();
    var str4=$("#invoice_code_nr").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'hotkeydetail.php',
      data:{'f3':str,'c4':str2,'c6':str3,'c7':str4}, 
      success: function(result){
          $('#txtHint').html(result);
      }
   });



}
```

Comment: look the my code where txtHint is id where i get record .. in your code i didn't how can send  these value data:{'f3':str,'c4':str2,'c6':str3,'c7':str4}, and also how to get

Comment: actually problem is that response is come in only <div> tag while running on ie8 i need to get another html tag.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: how can i . don't mind but i have post necessary code. please tell me how can i explain more .

Comment: You said `actually problem is that response is come in only <div> tag while running on ie8 i need to get another html tag`. Which <div> or "another html" you are talking about?

Comment: yes i did'nt get response on ie8 but same code are running good on other browser why please help if u have any solution .. thank's